# How to stub getServerSideProps in cypress?

Tags: next.js, cypress, server-side-rendering

Is there a way in a Cypress test to stub a GraphQL query called with Next.JS `getServerSideProps`?

I have tried using `cy.intercept`, but, being the request done server side, `cy.intercept` doesn't seem to intercept it.

Comment: Might be worth having a look at [mocking server for SSR react app e2e tests with cypress.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47631821/mocking-server-for-ssr-react-app-e2e-tests-with-cypress-io).

Comment: I have manage to stub it successfully using [Mock Service Worker](https://mswjs.io/), but I have no way to change the returned mock before each test. When setting a handler with MSW it is set before cypress open...then I can't manage to `resetHandler` for a `serverWorker` from a test running instead in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like 'nock' which will spin up a BE server, and allow you to set up the responses to return when getServerSide executes as part of the cypress page test