# Mocking server side requests for end to end testing by cypress

Tags: testing, cypress, end-to-end

I am using Cypress for end to end tests. To test my payment process I need to mock the request of my back end(express) to bank for transaction. So when the cypress test clicks buy, a request goes to backend and the backend sends a request to bank for purchase, then the bank sends response to backend. So I need to test everything except requests to/from bank. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51439954/6687545) answer I assume there is no way to mock server side requests by cypress. Hope someone can show me that I am wrong and the way of doing that!
I was hoping that cypress plugins will let me to do that, but seems like I misunderstood the purpose of them.